# Type class that depends on another type class

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am writing a generic branch and bound implementation in Haskell. The algorithm explores the branch tree in this way (actually there is no bounding, to keep things simple):

```
- Start from an initial node and an initial solution.
- While there are nodes on the stack:
    - Take the node on the top.
    - If it's a leaf, then it contains a solution:
        - If it's better than the best one so far, replace it
    - Otherwise, generate the children node and add them on the top of the stack.
- When the stack is empty, return the best solution found.
```

What a solution and node are, it depends on the actual problem. How to generate children, whether the node is a leaf, how to extract a solution from a leaf node, it again depends on the actual problem.

I thought of defining two classes `Solution` and `BBNode` that requires those operations, along with a `BBState` type that stores the current solution. I also made a dummy implementation for two types `ConcreteSolution` and `ConcreteBBNode` (they do not make anything interesting, I just want the program to type check).

```
import Data.Function (on)

class Solution solution where
  computeValue :: solution -> Double

class BBNode bbnode where
  generateChildren :: bbnode -> [bbnode]
  getSolution :: Solution solution => bbnode -> solution
  isLeaf :: bbnode -> Bool

data BBState solution = BBState {
      bestValue :: Double
    , bestSolution :: solution
    }

instance Eq (BBState solution) where
  (==) = (==) `on` bestValue

instance Ord (BBState solution) where
  compare = compare `on` bestValue


branchAndBound :: (BBNode bbnode, Solution solution) => solution -> bbnode -> Maybe solution
branchAndBound initialSolution initialNode = do
  let initialState = BBState { bestValue = computeValue initialSolution
                             , bestSolution = initialSolution
                             }
  explore [initialNode] initialState

  where

  explore :: (BBNode bbnode, Solution solution) => [bbnode] -> BBState solution -> Maybe solution
  explore [] state =
    -- Completely explored the tree, return the best solution found.
    Just (bestSolution state)

  explore (node:nodes) state
    | isLeaf node =
      -- New solution generated. If it's better than the current one, replace it.
      let newSolution = getSolution node
          newState = BBState { bestValue = computeValue newSolution
                             , bestSolution = newSolution
                             }
      in explore nodes (min state newState)

    | otherwise =
      -- Generate the children nodes and explore them.
      let childrenNodes = generateChildren node
          newNodes = childrenNodes ++ nodes
      in explore newNodes state





data ConcreteSolution = ConcreteSolution [Int]
                      deriving Show

instance Solution ConcreteSolution where
  computeValue (ConcreteSolution xs) = fromIntegral . maximum $ xs

data ConcreteBBNode = ConcreteBBNode {
      remaining :: [Int]
    , chosen :: [Int]
    }

instance BBNode ConcreteBBNode where
  generateChildren node =
    let makeNext next = ConcreteBBNode {
                chosen = next : chosen node
              , remaining = filter (/= next) (remaining node)
              }
    in map makeNext (remaining node)

  getSolution node = ConcreteSolution (chosen node)
  isLeaf node = null (remaining node)



solve :: Int -> Maybe ConcreteSolution
solve n =
  let initialSolution = ConcreteSolution [0..n]
      initialNode = ConcreteBBNode {
                chosen = []
              , remaining = [0..n]
              }
  in branchAndBound initialSolution initialNode

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let n = 10
      sol = solve n
  print sol
```

However, this program does not type check. I get an error when implementing the function `getSolution` in the instance `BBNode`:

```
Could not deduce (solution ~ ConcreteSolution)
  from the context (Solution solution)
    bound by the type signature for
           getSolution :: Solution solution => ConcreteBBNode -> solution
```

In facts, I'm not even sure this is the right approach, since in `BBNode` class the `getSolution` function should work for *any* `Solution` type, while I only need it for *a single* concrete one.

```
  getSolution :: Solution solution => bbnode -> solution
```

I also tried using multi parameters type classes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

...

class (Solution solution) => BBNode bbnode solution where
  generateChildren :: bbnode -> [bbnode]
  getSolution :: bbnode -> solution
  isLeaf :: bbnode -> Bool

...

branchAndBound :: (BBNode bbnode solution) => solution -> bbnode -> Maybe solution
branchAndBound initialSolution initialNode = do
  let initialState = BBState { bestValue = computeValue initialSolution
                             , bestSolution = initialSolution
                             }
  explore [initialNode] initialState

  where

  explore :: (BBNode bbnode solution) => [bbnode] -> BBState solution -> Maybe solution
  explore [] state =
    -- Completely explored the tree, return the best solution found.
    Just (bestSolution state)

  explore (node:nodes) state
    | isLeaf node =
      -- New solution generated. If it's better than the current one, replace it.
...
```

But it still does not type check, at line:

```
  | isLeaf node =
```

I get the error:

```
  Ambiguous type variable `solution0' in the constraint:
    (BBNode bbnode1 solution0) arising from a use of `isLeaf'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is a typical problem solved by [functional dependencies](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_dependencies) or [associated types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families).

You're second approach is almost correct. `bbnode` and `solution` types are connected, i.e. `solution` type is uniquely determined by `bbnode` type. You use functional dependencies or associated types to encode this relationship in Haskell. Here is FD example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}
module Main where

import Data.Function

class Solution solution where
  computeValue :: solution -> Double

class (Solution solution) => BBNode bbnode solution | bbnode -> solution where
  generateChildren :: bbnode -> [bbnode]
  getSolution :: bbnode -> solution
  isLeaf :: bbnode -> Bool

data BBState solution = BBState {
      bestValue :: Double
    , bestSolution :: solution
    }

instance Eq (BBState solution) where
  (==) = (==) `on` bestValue

instance Ord (BBState solution) where
  compare = compare `on` bestValue

branchAndBound :: (BBNode bbnode solution) => solution -> bbnode -> Maybe solution
branchAndBound initialSolution initialNode = do
  let initialState = BBState { bestValue = computeValue initialSolution
                             , bestSolution = initialSolution
                             }
  explore [initialNode] initialState

  where

  explore :: (BBNode bbnode solution) => [bbnode] -> BBState solution -> Maybe solution
  explore [] state =
    -- Completely explored the tree, return the best solution found.
    Just (bestSolution state)

  explore (node:nodes) state
    | isLeaf node = undefined
```

Note the definition of `BBNode` type class. This program typechecks.

Another way to do this is associated types, but I don't remember exactly how to put typeclass boundary on associated types. Maybe someone else will write an example.

Comment: Adding a bound is straightforward with associated types, if slightly odd at first glance: `class D (T a) => C a where type T a :: *`.